# Remove duplicates without shifting cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with two columns, one contains the name of an issue on a computer and the other the concatenated serial numbers of the computers with this issue.

The point of the Excel sheet is to find the best combination of issues to fix in priority, i.e. the most present combination of issues among the computer park.

Here is a data sample:

```
Issue          Serials
Dead SSD     SN0125;
Dead CPU     SN0125;SN0452;
Dead Screen  SN0785;SN0452;SN0125;
Dead Ram     SN0785;SN0452;SN0658;SN0125;SN0111
```

This means that SN0125 will be reusable after we've fixed it's SSD, while SN0111 will be reusable after we've fixed it's ram, screen, cpu and SSD.
There isn't any pattern nor order in the concatenation of serials.

I want, if a Serial appears in a row, it shouldn't appear in the rows beneath, so I get something like this.

```
Issue          Serials
Dead SSD     SN0125;
Dead CPU     SN0452;
Dead Screen  SN0785;
Dead Ram     SN0658;SN0111;
```

I tried looping through the rows and remove duplicate serials using replace but ended up with empty serial cells.
Here is the code i tried:

```
For i = 2 To las_row
    s1 = Cells(i, 2)

    For j = i To las_row
        'We look for the content of the previous row, inside the next and remove it
        s2 = Cells(j, 2)
        Cells(i, 2) = Replace(s1, s2, "")
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the cell's value and look for a wildcard match above the current row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub prioritize()

    Dim m As Variant, arr As Variant, r As Long, i As Long, str As String

    With Worksheets("sheet1")

        For r = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            'split the cell value on a semi-colon delimiter
            arr = Split(.Cells(r, "B").Value2, Chr(59))

            'look for a previous match
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                m = Application.Match(Chr(42) & arr(i) & Chr(42), .Columns("B"), 0)
                If m < r Then arr(i) = vbNullString
            Next i

            'put the array back together then repair it and put it into the cell
            str = Join(arr, Chr(59))
            Do While InStr(1, str, Chr(59) & Chr(59)) > 0: str = Replace(str, Chr(59) & Chr(59), Chr(59)): Loop
            Do While Left(str, 1) = Chr(59): str = Mid(str, 2): Loop
            Do While Right(str, 1) = Chr(59): str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1): Loop
            .Cells(r, "B") = str
        Next r

    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, i just modified your code so that it keeps the ";" at the end of each serial but it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Variant using `split()` and `Scripting.Dictionary`:

```
Sub test()
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    Dim cl As Range, data As Range, x As Variant

    Set data = Range([B2], Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

    For Each cl In data
        For Each x In Split(cl.Value2, ";")
            If dic.exists(x) Then
                cl.Value2 = Replace(cl.Value2, x & ";", "")
            Else
                dic.Add x, Nothing
            End If
        Next x
    Next cl
End Sub
```

*test*

[image]